# How to display records from a Firebase database using a condition with Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following Firebase database:

[image]

All i want to do, is to display all the lists that belong to a specific user. In this case, i want to display List `aaa` and List `bbb` that belong to gmail@gmail,com user. With this query:

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

Query query = databaseReference.child("Lists").orderByChild("ListName");
firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ListModel>(this, ListModel.class, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, query) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, ListModel slm, int position) {
            ((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(slm.getListName());
        }
    };
```

I achieve to display all the lists but i want to display only the lists that belong to a single user and has the value of `true`. How can i do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please, try to change your data structure by https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data

Comment: This is exaclty what i have done. Before structuring my database, i have followed that instructions. Do you have any idea for solving this? Thanks.

Comment: I think you have to create user-Lists child if you will need Lists for specific user by big data.

Comment: I have another model, named `Users` in which i store user details, like: name, email and so on. There is also a node named: `Lists` where i store the lists like this: `-Kbvh8YjyVVp0fkC0hn6: "true"`. How can solve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't help. Do you have unique key in model Users ? You have to create model user-lists like fbproject -> User-Lists -> UserKey -> Listkey1 -> data of list

Comment: Yes, this exactly what i have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this behaviour.

1. `Query query = DatabaseRef.getReference().child("Lists").orderByChild("Users").equals("gmail@gmail,com")`

Then add the ChildEventListener to this reference

2. In Firebase data structure, make the email id parent and add all the childs under it, like

Lists
         \gmail@gmail,com
                                         \listName aaa
                                         \listName bbb

You can get data from this structure from below reference:

`Query query = DatabaseRef.getInstance().child("Lists").child("gmail@gmail,com")`

Then add ChildEventListener listener with your ref object.

Hope this will work for you..

--- Edited ----
Try using this:

```
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference ref = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Lists").orderByChild("Users").equalTo("gmail@gmail,com");

ref.addChildEventListener(New ChildEventListener......);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but in the first case, nothing is displayed. Remember, i need to display the lists. Regarding the second, i need to keep this database structure. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: I also have almost similar data structure in Firebase and able to get the complete list by using the 1st Option. Is it possible for you to share your code ?

Comment: I Have updated the code, please incorporate this, this should work for sure.

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing is displayed :|

Comment: Make sure the query you are passing is having exactly same data as you won't get data if data stored in captial letters and you are querying in small letters.

Comment: There are the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134760/discussion-between-alex-m-and-deepesh).